# Missing class by jar execution : NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: gradle, build, jar, noclassdeffounderror

building an executable jar in Intellij IDEA, using Gradle. I created an executable file by assembling. However there is a problem with class loading at execution, see the script and error message below. Am I missing some more settings?

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:5.2.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'

group 'com.company.project'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:30.0-jre'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.company.model.Main'
    }
}
```

**Error Message**

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar /home/user/Documents/Java/Projects/project/build/libs/project-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/Table
    at com.company.model.Main.main(Main.java:6)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.Table
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
```

Comment: The shadow plugin doc says that you should run `application-shadow.jar`, not `application.jar`. Here, you run `project-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`. Find the `-shadow` jar and run that instead. Also, you should fix your tags to reflect that accordingly.

Comment: yes, it is true, I used the shadow to compile instead of gradle. Basically use ShadowJar to produce an jar file. And it works